# Broken Section Numbering on Mandatory Template

Tags: microsoft-word

What I have:
1)  Microsoft Office (Word) ProPlus 365 on Windows 10
2)  A Word template mandated for use, made on an unknown version of Word
3)  Broken section and subsection numbering.

Specifically, the document defines a multiline numbering list with (at least) three levels of section headings.  It appears to be broken as I will describe below, but I do not have the option of scrapping it, I must fix it or the document.

Here is what the number should look like:

```
1 section one
2 section two
A section two A
B section two B
3 section three
A section three A
```

Here is what I get:

```
1 section one
2 section two
A section two A
B section two B
3 section three
C section three C
```

In other words, the heading level two numbering does not reset when the heading level one advances.  This behavior is replicated at the third level as well.  This is VERIFIABLY WRONG because the usage examples that go along with this show explicitly that what I call the correct numbering is what is desired.

The normal advice in this situation is to start over, or a pointer to any number of various sites showing how to start over with the assumption that this will let someone fix the issue.  However, despite some passing familiarity with creating numbered list formats, when I investigate the details of the heading styles, I do not see anything I could check or uncheck that would change the change between the 'right' and the 'wrong' number styles.

So what I hope for is one of the two following things:
1)  Detailed guidance on what might be going wrong in the numbered list styles,
2)  Some way to manually reset the number at lower levels when it screws up (thankfully it's a ten page document on a template I need to use once, not a hundred page document on a template I need to live with.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though what's causing your issue is the **Restart list after** setting for the level-2 headings. There is a check box for this, but it's initially hidden.

1. On the **Home** tab, in the **Paragraph** group, click the **Multilevel List** button, and then click **Define New Multilevel List**. (It's helpful if your cursor is in one of the heading paragraphs before you do this.)

   The dialog box that appears will show the settings for the current multilevel list that's used to number headings in your document.
2. Under **Click level to modify**, select **2**, since the issue involves the second level of the multilevel list.
3. Click the **More** button to expand the dialog box.
4. In the expanded dialog box, find the **Restart list after** check box. From your description, it sounds as though this is currently cleared (not checked) for list level 2. Therefore, select (check) the check box, and then select **Level 1** in the drop-down list. The **Start at** field should be set to **A** automatically.
5. If necessary, repeat steps 2 through 4 for list levels 3 and below. In step 4, select **Level 2** in the drop-down list if you're adjusting list level 3, select **Level 3** for list level 4, and so on.
6. Click **OK**.

Any headings that are added or styled in the future should now be correctly numbered or lettered.

For the level-2 headings that are currently numbered (lettered) incorrectly, you can manually reset the numbering by right-clicking one of the letters that should be 'A' and then clicking **Restart at A**. (For other heading levels, the name of the menu command may be **Restart at 1**, **Restart at a**, **Restart at i**, or something else, depending on the setup of the multilevel list.)

Comment: This is exactly they type of answer I am looking for.  The first suggestion did not help (the list seems set appropriately despite its behavior) and the second produces strange changes in the alignment and tabbing, but seems to be workable overall.  I will not have a chance for several days to go through the whole document, but I expect to be able to accept the answer when I do.